# Rails redirect_to custom login route from ApplicationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to redirect to a custom route if the user not signed in and I am doing this in ApplicationController as below.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :authenticated!

  def authenticated!
     unless user_signed_in?
       redirect_to login_path
     end
  end
end
```

And this is my Sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
   include Devise::Controllers::Helpers
   include Devise::Controllers::SignInOut
   
   #custom login
   def new
     render layout: false
   end
end
```

Here is my custom route:

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
   devise_for :users
   root "home#index"
   get 'login', to: 'sessions#new', as: 'login' #this is the custom route
   get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
  end
```

Now, if the user not logged in, it trying to redirect but something preventing this and I am not sure if it happens because of Devise things.

Here is the screenshot of the issue.
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the before action is disabled for the `login_path`?

Comment: You need to allow unauthenticated users to get to the session controller.

Comment: @JanVítek I am not sure, do i need to that and how?

Comment: @dbugger how should i do that please? i am new to Rails

Comment: The easiest way to have the Sessions controller inherit from the Devise:Sessions controller -- not the application controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should use `authenticate_user!` method which is defined by Devise for the redirection. It will automatically allow unauthenticated users to access routes in `Devise::SessionController` required for authentication.
2. For custom controllers and views you should follow the [heartcombo/devise](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise) README page (sections [Configuring views](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#configuring-views) and [Configuring controllers](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#configuring-controllers)). There are described generators which will place the files you want to edit to correct paths in `/app/`. Don't forget to alter the routes for customized controllers (also described in [Configuring controllers](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#configuring-controllers))

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
   include Devise::Controllers::Helpers
   include Devise::Controllers::SignInOut

   skip_before_action :authenticated!, only: [:new]
   
   #custom login
   def new
     render layout: false
   end
end
```

Currently, when you try to `redirect_to login_path`, your `new` action finds that the user is not logged in and redirects to your `new` action, which finds that the user is not logged in and redirects to your `new` action, which finds that the user is not logged in and... (on to infinity).

As noted in the comments, you'll need to add any other actions (such as `:create`) to the `skip_before_action` call that you do not want subject to the `before_action`.

Comment: It redirects me back to login page if the user cred is correct or not

Comment: Please clarify your question. Redirecting to `login_path` when `user_signed_in?` is truthy is a different problem than a redirect that will never complete. The error message you posted suggests the latter (redirect that will never complete). However, your comment suggests the former (redirect to login_path when user_signed_in is truthy).

Comment: @jvillian your code wouldn't work because it opens only `:new` (GET the form). For a successful authentication you need to add at least `:create` (POST the form). Otherwise you will be redirected back to the login form when you try to submit it.

Comment: @JanVítek point well taken. I've added an additional note.